# Message inheritance and getting access to the message from consumer

Tags: c#, oop, masstransit

First of all, I'm aware that [inheritance is not quite good and we should be careful with it](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/understand/message-contracts.html), but...

In a system I have set of different commands that I publish to the bus in order to trigger appropriate services. Now I want to log the fact that some of messages (not all messages, just a subset) were issued.

I was thinking that the ideal way to handle it would be some separate service that just subscribed to the list of messages that I'm interested in, catches it and logs it.

What is the best way to implement it?

I was thinking about using inheritance like this

```
public interface IAction
{
}


public interface TestCommand : IAction
{
    Guid Id { get; }
    string Message { get; }
}


public class TestHandler : IConsumer<IAction>, IConsumer<TestCommand>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IAction> context)
    {
        var action = context.Message;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TestCommand> context)
    {
        var cmd = context.Message;
    }
}
```

but the problem here that `IAction` consumer doesn't have access to the whole message, so I just can't get the content to log.

Is it possible to solve this somehow and get access to the message content? Or, this approach is totally wrong and I should use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `context.TryGetPayload<YourMessageType>(out var message)` but again you need to know the message type.

You can also consume (or get payload of) the `JObject`, which will give you everything in plain JSON.

Observers is better for logging, check the Audit feature to see how it can be done.

Comment: Cool! Thank you, Alexey! Just found example how to consume it as JToken here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35354796/524605

Comment: Interesting idea about Observers... will analyse it

Comment: Yeah, this was my question from a couple of years back :) This is one way to log, in case you want to centralise it and receive any message that passes through the system. Observers are better when you want separate logs per service of you only want to observe specific messages,

Answer (score -1):

You should move the declaration of your

```
string Message { get; }
```

to

```
public interface IAction
```

I mean, every command will havec a Message and an Id right ?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to avoid... I have separate commands with different content and I don't want to move all the possible options into one IAction interface.

Comment: And what about using reflection ? Something like :    
    typeof(TestCommand ).GetProperty("Message").GetValue(context);